# Handler button click MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, event-handling

I'm newbie in MVC4 and i have some problem with handle button click.

Index.cshtml:

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<div class="logo">
    <br />
    <img alt="" src="../../Images/logo.png" />
    <br />
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/PartialView/Login.cshtml");
</div>
</form>
```

Login.cshtml:

```
@model AP.MVC4.Models.User

<fieldset>
    <legend><b>
        @Html.ViewBag.login_text
    </b></legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    @Html.ViewBag.user_name
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model=>Model.ID, new { style = "width:60%;" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    @Html.ViewBag.password
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.PasswordFor(Model=>Model.Password, new { style = "width:60%;" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "HomeController", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <input id="btnLog" type="submit" value="@Html.ViewBag.login" />
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

HomeController.cs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.login = Resources.LocalString.login;
        ViewBag.login_text = Resources.LocalString.login_text;
        ViewBag.user_name = Resources.LocalString.user_name;
        //....Some other code
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string user, string pw) {
        MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create();
        string Pw_hash = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, pw);
        DataTable dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetLoginDetail"
            , new SqlParameter("@UserName", user.Trim())
            , new SqlParameter("@Password", Pw_hash.ToLower())).Tables[0];
        //...Some other code
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

User model:

```
public class User
{
    private const string RequireMessage = "Bắt buộc";
    [Required(ErrorMessage = RequireMessage)] 
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = RequireMessage)] 
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = RequireMessage)] 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BirthDay { get; set; }
    public string CMND { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have 2 other textbox for username and password. There are 2 problems when I click the button

1. "Login" action in my controller was not fire
2. Information was sent to url like:

   ```
   http://localhost:31648/?ID=administrator&Password=123
   ```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Post you code that generates the inputs for username and password (the  names of the controls do not appear to match the parameters or your post action method)

Comment: I have just update all the code, please take a look

Comment: The inputs generated by `@Html.TextBoxFor` and `@Html.PasswordFor` need to be inside the form element (see code for the _View_ in  Ehsan's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the mistake.  You should change `HomeController` to `Home`.  You have to pass Controller Name without the postfix Controller:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="ID"/>
    <input type="password" name="Password"/>
    <input id="btnLog" type="submit" value="@Html.ViewBag.login" />
}
```

And action parameters should match the input element name:

### Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string ID, string Password) 
{
    //Some code here
    return View("Index");
}
```

More better way is to use strongly typed view:

```
public class LoginModel
{    
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }    
}
```

### View:

```
@model LoginModel 

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.ID)
    @Html.PasswordFor(x=>x.Password)
    <input id="btnLog" type="submit" value="@Html.ViewBag.login" />
}
```

And in Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{    
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model) 
    {
        //Some code here
        return View("Index");
    }    
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. And my class is HomeController, why only use "Home" ?

Comment: we have to pass only controller name without controller postfix

Comment: I found the problem, it because in Index.cshtml i have a <form> tag surround everything.

Comment: you have form inside form?

Comment: you should have posted your complete view, you only posted the mvc Helper form

Answer (score 0):

without more code to go off of, it appears your problems are:

1. Your username and password fields have id's called `ID` and `Password`, while your controller expects parameters `user` and `pw`, change either the view or the controller so they match up.
2. Your URL looks like you're sending an http `GET` request, make sure it's a `POST`
3. As Ehsan said, don't use the `Controller` suffix on your `HomeController` to reference it in your view.